# What is recommended analyzer / filter for human names in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder whether there are recommendations for using analyzers / filters to index/search for human names.

Examples of names that might pose difficulties:

- Marc  versus Mark
- Peter de Langhe  versus  Peter delange
- Verhaeven  versus  Verhaven
- François  versus  Francois

thx
Marc

Comment: Not really what you asked for, but I'm leaving this here, as it is a must read for everyone programatically processing names: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/
Found it on slashdot a few years ago. Hopefully you find it relevant and useful.

Comment: I can only guess, but it looks like you would probably benefit most from phonetic matching, which is available as [an elasticsearch plugin](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an analyzer and filter to get you started. It's hard to cover all the cases, but an `asciifolding` filter will solve your issues with the *François versus Francois* case.

In the example below, it will preserve the original so that a query for both François and Francois will resolve to the same resultset.

```
        "analyzer": {
            "name_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "trim",
                    "my_ascii_folding"
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "my_ascii_folding" : {
                "type" : "asciifolding",
                "preserve_original" : true
            }
        }
```

[Source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html)

By defining a synonym filter, you can define a list of commonly similar names in your language (maybe a line like `François => Francois` in your synonyms file for example) that will do the trick in the short run.

Lastly a `pattern_replace` char filter with a `"([A-Za-z]+)ae([A-Za-z]+)" => "$1a$2"` pattern can turn all the `Verhaeven` into `Verhaven`

Something like...

```
        "char_filter": {
            "ae_char_filter": {
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "pattern": "([A-Za-z]+)ae([A-Za-z]+)",
                "replacement": "$1a$2"
            }
        }
```

Even *Peter de Langhe versus Peter delange* can be solved with a `pattern_replace` char filter:

```
        "char_filter": {
            "de_char_filter": {
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "pattern": "([A-Za-z]+) de ([A-Za-z]+)",
                "replacement": "$1 de$2"
            }
        }
```